# Parser of ini-file with duplicate names for Java

Tags: java, parsing, ini

There is a configuration file in the following format:

```
[section1]
key1=value1
key2=value2

[section2]
key3=value3
key4=value4

...

[section2]
key3=value5
key4=value6
```

The problem is that we should not merge the keys that belong to the sections of the same name.

**Ini4j** merges them into one section: `[[section2], key3, key4]`

Is there a java-parser, which returns list of sections, not set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ini.getConfig().setMultiSection(true);
```

Comment: Don't working. `ini = new Wini();
   ini.getConfig().setMultiSection(true);
   ini.load(new File(configName));
   System.out.println("Number of sections: "+ini.size()+"\n");` Output 2, must be greater.

Comment: Yes, it is 2. However each element is an array containing the **list** of sections. Try doing `ini.getAll("section2").size()`

Answer (score -1):

Just an example of the above with multi section and multi values per section:

**Config.ini**

```
[section2]
key3=value1
key4=value2
key5=value3.1
key5=value3.2

[section2]
key3=value4
key4=value5
key5=value6.1
key5=value6.2
```

**code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.ini4j.Ini;
import org.ini4j.InvalidFileFormatException;
import org.ini4j.Profile.Section;

public class TestConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            File file = new File("config.ini");
            Ini ini = new Ini();
            ini.getConfig().setMultiSection(true);
            ini.load(file);


            List<Section> sections = ini.getAll("section2");
            for(Section section : sections)
            {
                System.out.println("key3: " +  section.get("key3"));
                System.out.println("key4: " +  section.get("key4"));
                List<String> values = section.getAll("key5");
                for(String val : values)
                {
                    System.out.println("key5: " + val);
                }
                System.out.println("***********************************");
            }


        } catch (InvalidFileFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
key3: value1
key4: value2
key5: value3.1
key5: value3.2
***********************************
key3: value4
key4: value5
key5: value6.1
key5: value6.2
***********************************
```